# Problem while installing vlc player

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies, vlc

I can't install vlc player on my Ubuntu(14.04).
I have read [this](http://tecadmin.net/install-vlc-on-ubuntu/) and try to run the commands, but while I run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

I got something like this:

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.4+git20150226+r54594+19+11~ubuntu14.04.1) but 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1 is to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.1.4+git20150226+r54594+19+11~ubuntu14.04.1) but 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1 is to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 2.1.4+git20150226+r54594+19+11~ubuntu14.04.1) but 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What is the problem? Have you any Idea to solve this or Could you please tell me the right procedure by which I can install vlc media player?

---

**Update:**

After removing the PPA, this is the output of `apt-cache policy vlc`:

```
vlc: 
  Installed:  (none) 
  Candidate:  2.1.2-2build2 
    Version table: 
      2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1 0 
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status 
      2.1.2-2build2 0 
        500 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/universe i386 Packages 
      2.0.1-4 0 
        500 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise/universe i386 Packages
```

And The command:

```
apt-cache policy vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse
```

gives me the following results:

```
vlc-nox:
  Installed: 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1
  Candidate: 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.1.2-2build2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages
     2.0.1-4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe i386 Packages
vlc-plugin-notify:
  Installed: 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1
  Candidate: 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.1.2-2build2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages
     2.0.1-4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe i386 Packages
vlc-plugin-pulse:
  Installed: 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1
  Candidate: 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.1.2-2build2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages
     2.0.1-4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe i386 Packages
```

Comment: Try this first: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa

Comment: Oh no its not working.

Comment: What did you try and what did you get as a response. Kindly edit your question and include that information.

Comment: I've run all the commands step by step according to the post but still unable to install the vlc.

Comment: You upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04? There are still the old 12.04 repositories left enabled. Run `sudo sed -i '/precise/d' /etc/apt/sources.list` to remove them from your configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the PPA, install `vlc` from the Ubuntu repositories.

1. Remove the PPA you have installed:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:videolan/stable-daily
   ```
2. Empty the package cache:

   ```
   sudo apt-get clean
   ```
3. Update your package lists:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Downgrade/install all vlc packages to/in the repository version:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall vlc=2.1.2-2build2 vlc-data=2.1.2-2build2 vlc-nox=2.1.2-2build2 vlc-plugin-notify=2.1.2-2build2 vlc-plugin-pulse=2.1.2-2build2
   ```

---

Depending on your Ubuntu version, you might currently (Nov 20, 2015) get a VLC version up to **2.2.1-3** on Wily (15.10). Older Ubuntu versions might have older VLC versions in their repositories.

You check the versions available for you with the command:

```
apt-cache policy vlc
```

An example output on my 15.10 64bit system would be:

```
vlc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.2.1-3
  Version table:
     2.2.1-3 0
        500 http://[YOUR REPOSITORY SERVER URL]/ wily/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: I have followed your instructions but still got the same problems....
and 

'apt-cache policy vlc'

gives me the following info:

'vlc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.1.2-2build2
  Version table:
     2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.1.2-2build2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages
     2.0.1-4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe i386 Packages'

Comment: That's strange. You get the exactly same error as above in the question? And the precise (12.04) repositories should not have been enabled. Anyway, please edit your question to provide new command outputs, the formatting gets destroyed in comments and it's harder to find. Add the output of `apt-cache policy vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse` to your question please and leave ma a comment here after you finished the edit. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, and run `sudo apt-get clean` and perform steps 2 and 3 of my answer again.

Comment: You need to downgrade the installed versions of these three packages from the version in the PPA to the version in the repositories: `sudo apt-get install vlc-nox=2.1.2-2build2 vlc-plugin-notify=2.1.2-2build2 vlc-plugin-pulse=2.1.2-2build2`. I edit my answer and insert steps 2 and 3.

Comment: I think vlc has installed now, but I still have some problem to run vlc. :(

Comment: What problem? Please describe, if it's related to the VLC installation, or ask a new question if it's different. Then also don't hesitate to accept my answer by clicking the grey tick button on the left of it. Also make sure you have read the [tour] page of AskUbuntu to learn a bit more about our site.

Comment: After finishing installation, I run command: vlc and it shows:
VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind (revision 2.1.6-0-gea01d28)
[0x834b910] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0x836f438] skins2 interface error: no suitable dialogs provider found (hint: compile the qt4 plugin, and make sure it is loaded properly)
[0x836f438] skins2 interface error: cannot instantiate qt4 dialogs provider
[0x836f438] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 2.1.2 Rincewind
Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
>

Comment: You need to downgrade the VLC package as well, it seems: `sudo apt-get install vlc=2.1.2-2build2`. After that it really should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31863/discussion-between-shikhor-roy-and-byte-commander).